# Conditional class template constructor

Tags: c++, templates, template-meta-programming

I am trying to make a class that has conditional members as below (sample code to illustrate problem):

```
template<bool b>
struct conditional_members {};

template<>
struct conditional_members<true> 
{ int m; };

template<typename T, bool b>
struct my_class : public conditional_members<b>
{
    T n;

    // constructor for case when b is false
    my_class(T n) : n(n) {};

    // constructor for case when b is true
    my_class(T n, int m) : n(n), m(m) {};
};
```

I need to have two conditional constructors depending on the `bool b` but this does not compile. I tried specializing the constructors with bool value:

```
template<typename T>
my_class<T, true>::my_class(T n, int m) : n(n), m(m) {};

template<typename T>
my_class<T, false>::my_class(T n) : n(n) {};
```

but that doesn't compile either because partial function template specializations are not allowed.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: `m` is not a member, initialize the base class instead.

Comment: What problem are you trying to achieve by having a structure like this?

Comment: @Igor I believe `m` is a member by inheritance when `b` is true

Comment: @NathanOliver this is a small piece of code to illustrate the problem. `my_class` would have other member functions that could need `conditional_members` in some situations but not always. The members of `conditional_members` can be large in size so I don't want to always have them even when they are unused.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with

```
// constructor for case when b is true
my_class(T n, int m) : n(n), m(m) {};
```

is that a constructor's mem-initializer-list can name only virtual base classes, direct base classes, and direct non-static data members, but never an inherited member like `m`.  This is because the member of a base class is initialized by the base class subobject constructor, so it can't be initialized again (though it could be assigned).

You can instead specify the base class initializer. With this example, `conditional_members` is an aggregate, so aggregate initialization will work:

```
// constructor for case when b is true
my_class(T n, int m) : n(n), conditional_members<b>{m} {};
```

Though with just that, you might get some strange side effects from the fact that `my_class` specializations always have the two constructors declared, even if it might be invalid to actually instantiate one constructor or the other.

Here's an SFINAE trick to make the constructors conditionally effectively invisible, depending on `b`:

```
#include <type_traits>

// Define conditional_members as before.

template<typename T, bool b>
class my_class : public conditional_members<b>
{
    T n;

public:
    // constructor for case when b is false
    template <typename = std::enable_if_t<!b>>
    my_class(T n) : n(n) {}

    // constructor for case when b is true
    template <typename = std::enable_if_t<b>>
    my_class(T n, int m) : conditional_members<b>{m}, n(n) {}
};
```

---

As a preview, with C++20 constraints, you'll be able to write it this nice, simpler way instead:

```
template<typename T, bool b>
class my_class : public conditional_members<b>
{
    T n;

public:
    // constructor for case when b is false
    my_class(T n) requires(!b) : n(n) {}

    // constructor for case when b is true
    my_class(T n, int m) requires(b) : conditional_members<b>{m}, n(n) {}
};
```

Comment: Thanks! I had tried `enable_if` but I was still using the member initializer list instead of initializing `m` in constructor body using `this`.

Comment: Also, the `enable_if_t` doesn't work here because `b` is a bool and not `true_type` or `false_type`. Just using `enable_if` works fine though.

Comment: @Bilentor no need to assign `m` in the ctor body, just initialize the base class: `: conditional_members<b>(m)`

Comment: @Bilentor that's wrong, both `std::enable_if` and `std::enable_if_t` tempalates accept `bool` as their first parameter.

Comment: The first argument of `enable_if` or `enable_if_t` _is_ a `bool`. (`true_type` and `false_type` can convert to `bool` if you use them where `bool` is required, though.) Careful: using `enable_if` alone, without either the `_t` or `::type` will NOT trigger SFINAE.

Comment: @IgorR. Yes, initializing the base class is preferable, provided `conditional_members<true>` adds an appropriate constructor.

Comment: @aschepler it's aggregate, it doesn't need ctor to get initialized.

Comment: Why not use `my_class(T n, int m) : conditional_members<b>{m}, n(n) {}`?

Comment: @IgorR. Okay, except for aggregate initialization you need curly braces, not parentheses. `: conditional_members<b>{m}`

Comment: Edited to use aggregate base class initializers.